# Vagrant Determining IP information for eth2... failed

Tags: centos, mac-osx, virtualbox, vagrant, eth0

Im running a vagrant file to bring up a CentOS Virtual Box on OSX, but when running `vagrant up` it always fails at `default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...` with the error:

```
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.

Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

/sbin/ifup eth2 2> /dev/null

Stdout from the command:


Determining IP information for eth2... failed.


Stderr from the command:
```

I had a member of my team find a workaround for this relatively quickly, I believe they disabled the adaptor somehow either on the host or the guest but I have tried for hours and cannot seem to figure out how they did it.

I've tried [a lot of the solutions suggested](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/997), such as disabling `en2` on the host using `ifconfig en2 down`.

I've tried editing and removing the files on the guest at `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` but these are always rebuilt by vagrant.

I've tried editing the files on the guest at `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth2` to set `ONBOOT=no` but again these are rebuilt by vagrant.

The problem is that I do not have access to the original Virtual Box to edit any of the configuration before it is packaged.

This is a company Mac and this is the second one I have tried it on, although on a non-company Mac it did not have the same issue.

I know that there is a way to stop Vagrant trying to configure `eth2`, I just cant figure out how to do it (or any other workaround) without having the original Virtual Box.

Comment: What networks do you have in your `Vagrantfile`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that eth2 is the adaptor to connect the VirtualBox directly to the outside Internet, so commenting out

```
config.vm.network :public_network
```

from the VagrantFile stopped the public network interfaces being loaded and so solved the issue.